# Running pdfgrep command inside bash-shell script using Windows Subsystem for Linux with spaces in search pattern

Tags: bash

Currently Im using on Windows 10, subsystem for Linux Ubuntu 20.04 the command pdfgrep for to use in my script. Lets explain a little bit in more detail. I want to search in a pdf file in my folder for an articlenumber that contains spaces in it. But in my little script I get an error : first you see an echo with the whole pdfgrep command with the search pattern (= articlenumber) and the pdf file located in my folder

`/usr/bin/pdfgrep '4022 622 48402' ../testdir/'4022 622 48402 - B263486P010 DY 2022-8-22.pdf'` On the command line, above pdfgrep command seems to work fine.

Below is the part of my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# 
#
#
clear
echo
inputfile="`ls ../testdir/*.pdf`"
inputfile2="${inputfile:11:46}"
inputfile3=\'$inputfile2\'
doctp1=${inputfile: -3}
articlenumber1=${inputfile:11:14}
articlenumber2=\'$articlenumber1\'
echo
read -p "Running pdfgrep with articlenumber. Push a key to continue ! " x
clear
echo 
#case ${doctp1} in 
#          pdf) 
            clear
            echo "/usr/bin/pdfgrep ${articlenumber2} ../testdir/${inputfile3}"
            /usr/bin/pdfgrep ${articlenumber2} ../testdir/${inputfile3}
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then
                    echo "No pdf files with given articlenumber present"
            # echo "No pdf files with given articlenumber present" >>  log_$articlenumber1_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M").txt
            fi
            echo
            read -p "Push a key to continue !" x
```

When I run the script I got this error :

> pdfgrep: Could not open 622 pdfgrep: Could not open 48402' pdfgrep:
> Could not open ../testdir/'4022 pdfgrep: Could not open 622 pdfgrep:
> Could not open 48402 pdfgrep: Could not open - pdfgrep: Could not open
> B263486P010 pdfgrep: Could not open DY pdfgrep: Could not open
> 2022-8-22.pdf'

Can you help me with finding a solution for this ? Is there anything that I do wrong here ? Please let me know. All comments are welcome !

Comment: try `pdfgrep "${articlenumber2}"` inside your script

Comment: Never use `var=$(ls)`, that will always fail when there are any even slightly odd file names. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Thanks sofar ! I think these tips are very helpful, in some parts I think I need to rewrite my script to avoid these pitfalls.